# Alias not being resolved directly within an attribute in Twig templates

Tags: craft4, css, alias

Is this a bug or is this me ? (I'm a new to craft)

When using the @web alias directly within an attribute in a Twig template, the alias doesn't seem to be resolved to its corresponding URL. Instead, the literal string @web is rendered in the final output.

**Steps to Reproduce:**

1. Define the @web alias in general.php:

```
->aliases([
    '@web' => 'http://craftsite.ddev.site/'
])
```

2.Use the alias directly in a Twig template's attribute:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="@web/css/app.css">
```

3. View the rendered HTML. The output is:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="@web/css/app.css">
```

The expected output should be:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://craftbites.ddev.site/css/app.css">
```

**Workaround:**

Resolving the alias to a variable first and then using that variable in the attribute resolves the issue:

```
{% set baseUrl = alias('@web') %}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ baseUrl }}/css/app.css">
```

**Environment:**

- Craft version: 4.5
- PHP version: 8.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty sure you have to resolve the alias with twig, you could short it down to just:

```
<link refl="stylesheet" href="{{ alias('@web') }}/css/app.css">
```

But you also dont need the full url for the css file:

```
<link refl="stylesheet" href="/css/app.css">
```

Should work just fine too.

Comment: Thank you so much for pointing out the correct way to use the alias in Twig. I was stuck trying to use @web directly within an attribute, and I totally missed resolving it with {{ alias('@web') }}/css/app.css or just simplifying with the relative /css/app.css. It seems so clear now!